# Robust Industrial Camera sought which is small enough to fit

Tags: case, ethernet, camera, embedded-systems

For our project, we need to buy a robust industrial cabled camera (ethernet or usb) that is waterproof and has good shock resistance (up to ~50 g force), and has M-connectors (for protection). Also, the camera together with its protective housing has some physical constraints. Namely, in order to fit it must be less than 10 cm in the direction of the optical axis for one.

Such requirements make it hard to find the right suppliers/manufacturers.
Software specifications on the other hand are usually not a problem.

So I'm wondering, is there any such industrial camera(s) available anywhere (Preferably in Europe)? A company that sells them is of course also fine (if not better).

Alternatively, there might be camera housing manufacterers that produce the cases only, such that the camera comforms tho the aformentioned mechanical specifications?  If so, I'm interested in that as well.

An online search till now yields only few candidate results.
Happy to add more information if not clear.

---

**Edit 01**

The industrial setting that warrant these mechanical requirements is one in a container terminal, where the camera is attached beneath a crane.

Optical requirements are simply that the camera needs to be able to take rgb pictures of a resolution of at least 512 by 512 pixels.

The camera needs to be able to send this data via a cabled connection (no wireless connectivity available).

---

**Edit 02**

The kind of product we are selling involves lifting equipment for (shipping) containers. This camera hardware I described is used in combination with a *recognition algorithm* written by our company, that senses variables like presence/positioning et cetera, which is ultimately used for automation. So the only real use of this camera is that we simply need images, taken of our object of interest (containers).

But right now, we want to use it to speed up the working cycle (picking and placing) by a few seconds per cycle. So for the product to be feasible for us, it ought not be more expensive than say ~1000 euros in my estimation (preferably much less).

So it's not like we *can't afford* anything more expensive, rather it's just that we do not have any use for it, considering it facilicates just one of many features of our overall machine.

Comment: It would be helpful, I think, that you explain *why* you need such camera (especially in relation to 50 g, which is an... *unusual* requirement), and what do you qualify as “industrial,” as well as what are your expectations in terms of the image (which includes the choice of the optics).

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'm wondering if you should look at vandal-proof outdoor security cameras. The problem is that all the security cameras I know are much, much larger than your 10 cm requirement. Sport cameras are not an option, since they won't have an Ethernet port. And any webcams won't last long on a crane.

Comment: I strongly suspect you got a budget issue, otherwise getting such camera's isn't hard at all. Are you part of a company? Getting industrial-grade items as a private person is much harder than getting them as an employee (might be worth it to start a one-man company).

Comment: @Mast, did you consider the constraits I mentioned? If it's not hard, can you show examples perhaps? Thanks

Comment: [Imperx](https://www.imperx.com/camera-selector/) probably has what you want. They have cameras that get shot into space. But again, I strongly suspect you got budget constraints you didn't mention in your question. Otherwise not even the sky is the limit.

Comment: We already browsed their site. They refer to other suppliers as well. Many of their cameras do not fit, but we did find one though that does. Only thing is it costs about €3000, and as you can imagine, is not worth it for us to make a sellable product with it. We are considering some streaming cameras now that are 10 times cheaper, but storing images will require some alternative interface.

Comment: You don't tell us what kind of product you're selling, so I have no idea whether 3k is much or not. I mean, I've designer products where one motor would cost half of that already, not counting the rest of the equipment required to make that motor doing something useful. In the industrial world, equipment is expensive. That's not a problem, as long as you sell your product for more than it cost.

Comment: @Mast Edited the question to address some of your latest queries about the use-case.